# 'rhc setup' on Ubuntu 16.04 (openshift)

Tags: ubuntu, openshift

I tried the installation and configuration steps as described [here](https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/debian-ubuntu.html) für Openshift on Ubuntu

When I got to the point where I executed
    rhc setup
it just hangs and does nothing.

here is the output from my terminal:

```
$ rhc setup

OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application 
namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly 
installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just 
hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online: 
openshift.redhat.com.


You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
```

This is the point where it hangs.

I am not behind a proxy. I did not get any errors in previous setps in the installation guide. I worked before on my old machine with ubuntu 16.04. On my new machine it just hangs.

Comment: It isn't hanging. It is waiting for you to type the name of your OpenShift server (or just press enter to use the default).

Comment: Do be aware that ``rhc`` is for OpenShift V2. The latest version is V3 and uses a command line tool ``oc``. If you have signed up recently for latest OpenShift Online, you should not be using ``rhc``.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that rhc is for Openshift V2. I have been using openshift and rhc for several years now and I only have V2 cartidges. I am not new to this. @Quentin it was hanging and I did press enter otherwise it wouldn't have displayed the message "You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'." Anyway I dont know why, but after restarting ubuntu it worked. very strange. normally Ubuntu doesn't require restarts after installing software like ruby and rhc and git (by the way why am I getting negative rating for this Question?)

Answer (score 0):

solved! I restarted Ubuntu an after a fresh boot it worked. So anyone experiencing the same problems, just do a windows-style reboot